# SFML 1.6 without admin priviliges

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, sfml

So I have this SFML 1.6 application that works well on Mac OS X Lion. Currently the way I have it is that the SFML frameworks are in /Library/Frameworks and it works well, however to install on other machines it requires admin privileges. So I want to do one of the following:

1. Be able to install the libraries in /User/idk/Library/Frameworks or similar
2. Package the libraries and the app into a Mac disk image and have it reference the libraries from there
3. Statically link the libraries

Now since the program is built using the Terminal with makefiles, I would prefer the solution to be in the Terminal rather than XCode, but if absolutely necessary then I guess I could somehow import the project to XCode.

So can anyone explain (precisely) how to do any of the three above, whichever is the easiest to do?

By the way I'm using the LLVM GCC 4.2 that ships with XCode 4.1 for the compilation.

EDIT:

How about someone tries the other two, aside from statically linking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it so... kind of a waste of bounty points... SUCKS FOR YOU! :P

I did something quite simple and was surprised no one else had suggested it:

I used install_name_tool to change the names and dependencies of the SFML dynamic libraries so that they can be placed in the same directory as the executable, or in a special folder, but that's relative to the executable's directory. So it requires no admin privileges, and I easily packaged it all into an application bundle.

Comment: Upvoted for the good answer, but shame on you for depriving the people of their bounty! :)

Comment: I would always give the bounty if somebody gave a good and working solution. :D

Answer (score 2):

You should probably statically link to SFML. To do this you will have to compile SFML as a static library. The easiest way to do this is probably to modify the Xcode project that comes with SFML (`"SFML with Intel 64 bits.xcodeproj"`). You need to change the `Mach-O` type of the libraries to `Static Library`.

I've uploaded the modified version of `SFML with Intel 64 bits.xcodeproj` that I use, you can get it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hourglassii/files/Development-Packages/SFML_Xcodeproj.7z/download). (This project requires GCC4.2, and so only works with Xcode 3).

Statically linking to SFML is very similar to dynamically linking to it, just remember that you also need to link to `Cocoa.framework`, `OpenGL.framework`, and `CoreFoundation.framework`.

Also note that if you want to deploy to OSX 10.4 or earlier, you should statically link to `libfreetype`. The `libfreetype` that is supplied with the OS is in a different location in 10.4 and earlier, and this causes problems when it is dynamically linked.

Comment: XCode doesn't seem to like SFML now... it errors when compiling. Is there any other way to do this? Because it seems SFML 1.6 has problems with XCode on Mac 10.7...

Comment: @myrkos: What sort of problems? Please be more specific.

Comment: Alright. So basically, in the "Custom Shell Script" it says "cp: 3/build/xcode/../../include/SFML/: No such file or directory". That's the error.

Comment: @myrkos: What are you trying to do when you hit this error? Which "Custom Shell Script" is this, and what are its contents.

Comment: I'm trying to compile sfml-graphics, but that's just the one that happens to go first. "PhaseScriptExecution "Run Script" "build/SFML with Intel 64 bits.build/Debug/SFML.build/Script-A0BA42130DDF0E3F00039094.sh"" That is it's name... supposedly. I'm sorry, but I can't find anything else really to simplify the problem. It's a script that happens before the actual compilation.

Comment: Thank you for uploading the project file; I'll look into it as soon as I can.

Comment: @myrkos: Did you download [this](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sfml/SFML-1.6-sdk-macosx-ub32%2B64.tar.bz2) and replace the Xcode project in it with mine?

Comment: And yes, that is what I had downloaded.

Comment: @myrkos: It is the [7z format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z), on OSX it can be extracted with [keka](http://www.kekaosx.com/en/).

Comment: Also, you noted it only works in XCode 3, however I have GCC 4.2 but use XCode 4.1. Perhaps there's incompatibility between the different versions' project files?

Comment: @myrkos: Try changing the compiler from GCC4.2 to LLVM GCC4.2.

Comment: I tried your project file and changing the compiler, but neither worked. I get the same error, also a few warnings about the directories not existing... as if it's looking in the wrong place totally.

Comment: I gave you the bounty for the good effort, even though the solution didn't work :D